# Should we close garbhagruha of shivalaya with glass doors? Also any statues of deities?

Tags: shiva, temple, vastu-shastra

Recently I established shivaling and trustees had closed shivaling garbhgruha and idols of Lord ganesha and hanumanji with glass doors,

I am not able to breath properly. Is something unwanted?

Comment: A temple in our village doesn't have glass doors, but a simple door, its a shiva temple

Comment: The deities can't be packed inside doors, untill they have a  seprate shrine. Also, glass doors r not used. For eg, in Tirumala Jaya Vijaya r the doorkeepers of Garbhagriha, they r kept in a kind of fence so ppl dont touch them. But they r not, put under glass. U can ask the trust to come up with some other thing, to avoid causing problem to vigraha. As those have pranas. Thus, this according to me is a seriously unwanted.